# Can't set cookies in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, cookies

I thought cookies were simple, but I'm struggling with them for quite a while.

I'm trying to create cookies with the information and it does not work. It looks like the creation is not successful.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie;

Cookie::queue( Cookie::make('test', 'my test token', 5563));
```

I'm running `laravel` application on localhost as `http://localhost:8000/` or `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`
I read about issues with chrome and tried `FF` and `Edge` still do not understand where is the problem. Do I need to change to URL to `localhost.com`?

Comment: No, you don't need to change the URL. Can you show us the full context of the code here? These cookies won't set unless you return a Laravel response in a route (i.e. something like `return view('foo')`, `return response()->json(['foo'])`, etc.).

Comment: @ceejayoz Thanks. I understand now queue doesn't do anything until you redirect somewhere with a return response

Comment: Glad that helped, I've made that an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Cookie::queue` in Laravel only actually *sends* the queued cookie(s) if you issue [a Laravel response of some kind](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/responses). If you do your own responding (`print "OK";` sort of stuff) instead of using something like `return response()` or `return redirect()` or `return view()`, the cookie will be queued but never sent.